# Queries with Mobile Services Azure iOS

Tags: ios, sql, azure, azure-sql-database, objective-c++

I am trying to write a query that gets a row when the id is equal to 1 (at the moment).

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[apt[@"id"] isEqualToNumber:1]];
```

So where `id` (from another database) is equal to 1. Now this is complaining all sorts of things but its saying it needs to be a BOOL. Is NSPredicate needing a BOOL?

Not sure I understand, or is there another way I can query? Can I use T-SQL in Mobile Services SDK Azure for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The predicate with format expects a string, you are sending in a bool.  `[apt[@"id"] isEqualToNumber:1]` returns a bool.

Use the predicate in this manner (I have little experience with formatting predicates, so this will likely not actually work for you to copy and paste in).

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 1"];
```

This will work if your objects in the array you are filtering have a property called id.

Something I understand a littler better is predicates with blocks.  This could work for you too (I'm not entirely sure of your data structure, so you are gong to have to modify to suit your needs.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [object[@"id"] isEqualToNumber:1];  // Return YES for each object you want in filteredArray.
}]
```